# /etc/network/if-up.d script with password prompt

Tags: networking, bash

I want a script that logs me in when a specific interface uplink was established (university LAN).

The thing is I don't want to hardcode my password into the script. Is there any way to prompt for a password in a script in `if-up.d`?

For example this doesn't work because there is no DISPLAY variable set (setting one doesn't help):

```
# create temp file to store password
tmp=`tempfile`

xterm -e /bin/bash -c "read -s -p \"Enter password: \" mypassword; echo \"\$mypassword\" > $tmp"

# read in password and delete temp file
mypassword=`cat $tmp`
rm -f $tmp
echo $mypassword
```

Comment: No, there is no way to make if-up.d scripts interactive because they can be run at very early boot before you even have an X server running.

Also, when you store the password in the tmp file like that any process on the computer will be able to read the password. Not sure if that is a security issue for you.

Comment: Not as much of a security issue as storing it permanently on the drive. It would be possible checking if the system is in boot mode so this should be no problem. Aren't there any event triggered scripts? Any idea?

Comment: You could put the passphrase in a file with mode 600 if that is what you are concerned about.

Comment: Are you using a DE that runs with Upstart as a session init? If so I may have an idea...

Comment: You mean something like this? http://serverfault.com/questions/117584/upstart-scripts-run-a-task-after-networking-goes-up/117600#117600

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so mainly you will want to do two things: add a prompt when you start your desktop session, asking for your password, and make a prompt each time the interface is brought up again.

So, you will need to use an Upstart **session** job to guarantee you that an X session is started and the DISPLAY variable is set. Session jobs go in `~/.config/upstart/`, not `/etc/init/`, and they are run as a non-root user. You will need to make sure that your desktop sessions actually use Upstart as a session init. Unity definitely does this, some other Ubuntu flavors do as well. Just run `initctl list-sessions` to see if you have any Upstart sessions started to tell.

Anyway, here is the session job to use:

```
# change IFACE= to whatever interface it is, unless it is all interfaces.
# in that case just omit the IFACE=
start on desktop-start or :sys:net-device-up IFACE=eth99

task

# put your script in this location
exec /usr/local/bin/unilan-password
```

Also, you will most likely want to use Zenity to prompt the user, not an xterm. The following can be used instead of your bash command:

```
mypassword=$(zenity --entry --text="Enter University LAN password" --hide-text)
```

$(command) is just a nicer way to do command substitution than `command`, if you did not recognize it. Make sure you have the `zenity` package installed, of course.